# How to get other windows list in Electron

Tags: javascript, node.js, electron

Yes I know the title may suggest it's duplicate but it's actually not. I searched through internet for the solution but I couldn't find any.

My problem is how to get list (array) of all opened windows globally, not electron windows.
Something like Discord gets all apps processes and lists them in Activity in settings.

Comment: What have you tried so far??

Comment: Searching through docs, Stackoverflow and messing with it by myself.

Comment: Did you tried with process manager package?

Comment: Electron doesn't have the capability to provide such information by itself. If you are wanting this to be cross platform compatible then you will need to look into already created OS specific modules (Node.js or otherwise). Else, you may need to roll your own C++ module and use it via Node.js [C++ addons](https://nodejs.org/api/addons.html).

Answer (score 0):

You can try `ps-node` and `find-process` to get all running processes and get their names.

```
const ps = require('ps-node')
const find = require('find-process')

ps.lookup('', (Err, Programs) => {
    Programs.forEach(prog => {
        find('pid', prog.pid).then((progDetails) => {
            const procName = progDetails.map(stuff => stuff.name)[0]
            console.log(procName)
        })
    });
})
```

This may not be the cleanest way, but it works!